# Java HttpURLConnection no cookies

Tags: java, cookies, http-post, httpurlconnection, missing-cookies

English:

Hello, I'm currently trying to do a login with HttpURLConnection and then get the session cookies...

I already tried that on some test pages on my own server, and that works perfectly. When i send "a=3&b=5" i get "8" as cookie (PHP page adds both together)!
But when i try that at the other page, the output is just the page as if I just sent nothing with POST :(

General suggestions for improvement are welcome! :)

My Code:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("useragent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes("USER=tennox&PASS=*****");
out.close();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
String response = new String();
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response = response + line + "\n";
}
in.close();

System.out.println("headers:");
int i = 0;
String header;
while ((header = conn.getHeaderField(i)) != null) {
    String key = conn.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
    System.out.println(((key == null) ? "" : key + ": ") + header);
    i++;
}
String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
System.out.println("\nCookies: \"" + cookies + "\"");
```

Comment: Ich denke hier solltest Du die Fragen auf englisch stellen

Answer (score 1):

I see the following possibilities why you don't get a cookie.

- server does NOT send cookies at all
- server does not use the values PASS and USER
- server want to have a session before login.
- POST protocol is wrong or incomplete
- server expects parameters by GET

Comment: 1. where do they come from then, and who creates the cookies in the "Set-Cookie" header?
2. This particular Website has a <form> with these names
3. where do i get that from?
4. Please specify...
5. I'll try that :) (EDIT: doesn't work)

Thanks :)

Comment: I tried to describe my problem in english, hope you understand that better :)